# How to read a String from the clipboard in a codename one app?

Tags: android, ios, codenameone, clipboard

My app occasionally reads text data from the clipboard.  I'm using code like this, which seems to work ok on android.

```
String pasteText = null;
Object pasteObj = Display.getInstance()
                    .getPasteDataFromClipboard();   

if (pasteObj instanceof CharSequence) {
    pasteText = pasteObj.toString();
}
```

I'm wondering whether I am correct to use `CharSequence`, rather than `String`?  `String` would seem the intuitive choice, but didn't work for me when I tried it.

(I haven't tried the code on iOS.  Haven't yet signed up as a developer on Apple.)

Comment: I'm guessing that's correct but it might be something we would want to improve as this isn't very intuitive for most people. Can you please file an issue on this?

Comment: I added a comment to the issue at [https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1435](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1435) and linked back to this page.

Comment: @flewby Your link back to here is broken (its text is fine, but it links to elsewhere).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[That issue](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1435) is currently assigned to the 4.0 milestone which is planned for March 2018 so this should be addressed before that.